# How to disable all the NSLog in Xcode 5 in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have so many NSLog(@".."); in xcode for print the value. So when i release the app i want to disable all NSLog in my Xcode instead of doing //NSLog.

I have 2 questions.

1. When i use Nslog That time it show the result like below..

   ```
   2014-08-07 12:29:29.609 myapp_name[4694:70b] PHONENUMBER:1234567890
   2014-08-07 12:29:29.611 myapp_name[4694:70b] USERNAME: myname
   ```

But i don't like this type of output. I want only show the output like :

```
    PHONENUMBER:1234567890
    USERNAME: myname
```

2.Totally disable the NSLog, when i release the app.

Comment: To disable completely, put `#define NSLog(...)` in your prefix.pch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your question 1 Please follow this answer:

```
 #ifdef DEBUG
 #define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT,      ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
 #else
 #define NSLog(...) {}
 #endif
```

This is for only show the output like printf not like as NSLog----

For your question 2 Please follow this answer:

```
 #ifndef NDEBUG
 #define NSLog(...);
 #endif
```

It's working fine on xcode 5 and iOS 7 also. :)

Comment: @S R Nayak it will work for live app? or it will just work for degudmode?

Comment: so no need to remove code from .pch while uploading right? i mean it will not create any issue.

Comment: What happens: `#ifdef DEBUG` => "if  in debug configuration" `#define NSLog(...)`  => replace all instances of `NSLog` with any `(...)` parameters by the right hand side. This means pasting the first argument of NSLog as FORMAT, and the rest of the args go into `##__VA_ARGS__`.

Answer (score 1):

open your `.pch` file

add the following line

enable   //hide the all `NSLog`

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
#define NSLog(format, ...)
#endif
```

disable  //show the all `NSLog`

```
/*
#ifndef _DEBUG
#define NSLog(format, ...)
#endif
*/
```